# preg_match on HTTP_USER_AGENT

Tags: php, preg-match

I'm having to log IP addresses that come with a user agent of "Mozilla/5.0" (No webkit etc after it. Explicitly just Mozilla/5.0) or null. I've been playing around with preg_match but not having the best of luck. I know it's not the tidiest of code but it's just trying to get the job done. What changes do I need to make to the preg_match for it to work correctly?

```
<?php
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; 
    $agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];                                   
    $date = date("H:i dS F"); 
    $file = "log.html"; 

 if (preg_match("/\bMozilla\/5.0/", $agent))  {
            $open = fopen($file, "a+");
                fwrite($open, $ip . " | ".$agent." | ". $date); 
            fclose($open); 

} elseif (preg_match("/Null/", $agent))  {
            $open = fopen($file, "a+"); 
                fwrite($open, $ip . " | ".$agent." | ". $date);  
            fclose($open); 
} 
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TIP:
 - change **Delimiter** if `\` is in our string : see the [list](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php)
 - `\b` was not closed
 - use [`file_put_contents`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)

> This function is identical to calling fopen(), fwrite() and fclose()
>   successively to write data to a file.
>   If filename does not exist, the file is created. Otherwise.
>   using the FILE_APPEND flag to append the content to the end of the file
>   and the LOCK_EX flag to prevent anyone else writing to the file at the same time

try

```
<?php
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; 
    $agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];                                   
    $date = date("H:i dS F"); 
    $file = "log.html"; 

 if (preg_match("#\bMozilla/5.0\b#", $agent))
 {
  var_dump($agent);
  //return 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0'
  $content  =  " $ip  | $agent | $date ";
  file_put_contents($file, $content, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
  }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use strpos? Regex is overkill for this.

```
if (strpos($agent, 'Mozilla/5.0') !== false)
{
   //
}
else
{
   //
}
```

If you really want to use preg_match then this should work:

```
if (preg_match("/^Mozilla\/5\.0/", $agent))  {
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this function to get IP from useragent

```
<?php
# validip/getip courtesy of manolete <manolete@myway.com>
# IP Validation
function validip($ip) {
    if (!empty($ip) && $ip==long2ip(ip2long($ip))) {
        # reserved IANA IPv4 addresses
        # http://www.iana.org/assignments/ipv4-address-space
        $reserved_ips = array (
            array('0.0.0.0','2.255.255.255'),
            array('10.0.0.0','10.255.255.255'),
            array('127.0.0.0','127.255.255.255'),
            array('169.254.0.0','169.254.255.255'),
            array('172.16.0.0','172.31.255.255'),
            array('192.0.2.0','192.0.2.255'),
            array('192.168.0.0','192.168.255.255'),
            array('255.255.255.0','255.255.255.255')
        );

        foreach ($reserved_ips as $r)
            if ((ip2long($ip) >= ip2long($r[0])) && (ip2long($ip) <= ip2long($r[1])))
                return false; 
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

/* Patched function to detect REAL IP address if it's valid */
function getip() {
    if (getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP') && long2ip(ip2long(getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP')))==getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP') && validip(getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP')))
        return getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP');

    if (getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR') && long2ip(ip2long(getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')))==getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR') && validip(getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')))
        return getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR');

    if (getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED') && long2ip(ip2long(getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED')))==getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED') && validip(getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED')))
        return getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED');

    if (getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR') && long2ip(ip2long(getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR')))==getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR') && validip(getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR')))
        return getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR');

    if (getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED') && long2ip(ip2long(getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED')))==getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED') && validip(getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED')))
        return getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED');

    $ip = htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
    /* Added support for IPv6 connections. otherwise ip returns null */
    if (strpos($ip, '::') === 0) {
        $ip = substr($ip, strrpos($ip, ':')+1);
    }
   return long2ip(ip2long($ip));
}
?>
```